# Multiple ng-if on the same condition - performance wise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-show, angularjs-ng-if

I have a html page with different element, that according to some condition (the same condition) will be shown/hidden using Angular's ng-if.

In my controller, I create a `boolean` variable.

```
$scope.myCondition = getValue();
```

In my view, I listen to this variable using `ng-if` directive.

What will be better **performance** wise:

1. Write cleaner code **BUT** with multiple `ng-if` on this condition:

```html
<div>  
 <div ng-if="myCondition" >-- a --</div>
 <div ng-if="!myCondition">-- A --</div> 
 <div>
  -- text, text, text... --
 </div>
 <div ng-if="myCondition" >-- b --</div>
 <div ng-if="!myCondition">-- B --</div> 
 <div>
  -- text, text, text... --
 </div>
 <div ng-if="myCondition" >-- c --</div>
 <div ng-if="!myCondition">-- C --</div> 
 <div>
  -- text, text, text... --
 </div>
</div>
```

2. Write code duplication (in the view) **BUT** use single `ng-if`:

```html
 <div ng-if="myCondition">  
     <div>-- a --</div>
     <div>
      -- text, text, text... --
     </div>
     <div>-- b --</div>
     <div>
      -- text, text, text... --
     </div>
     <div  >-- c --</div>
     <div>
      -- text, text, text... --
     </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="!myCondition">  
     <div>-- A --</div>
     <div>
      -- text, text, text... --
     </div>
     <div>-- B --</div>
     <div>
      -- text, text, text... --
     </div>
     <div  >-- C --</div>
     <div>
      -- text, text, text... --
     </div>
    </div>
```

I will prefer writing code as displayed in example No.1, since it is more maintainable. But I concerned that this way a new `$watch` will be created for each `ng-if`. 
Is that correct? does Angular create new `$watch` for each `ng-if`, although this is the same static condition (not return value of some function but a simple variable).

This question asked regarding the `ng-if` directive but relevant also to `ng-show` and `ng-hide`

Comment: Each would have it's own watch so from performance standpoint you are correct that 2nd would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, you will create a watcher for every used ng-if, so in terms of performance is better to use the second option.

However, if your condition is going to be evaluated only once (when the controller executes its code) you can use the **one-time-binding operator ::** with ng-if to avoid $watchers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more approach of attain same desired result similar to your 1st approach by using `ng-switch`.Here is the [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/SaRaUBt0q00deHNu2NRu?p=preview) on how it works.

Below is your HTML by using `ng-switch`

```
<body ng-app="switchExample">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <input type="text" ng-model ="searchTerm" ng-change="getDisplayText()"/> 
  <code>selection={{searchTerm}}</code>
  <hr/>
  <div class="animate-switch-container"
    ng-switch on="myCondition">
      <div  ng-switch-when="Home">Home page</div>
      <div  ng-switch-when="show test">Test Sample</div>
      <div  ng-switch-default>default</div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

In your JS you will have

```
(function(angular) {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('switchExample', ['ngAnimate'])
        .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

            $scope.getDisplayText = function() {
                $scope.myCondition = getValue($scope.searchTerm);
            };
            $scope.myCondition = getValue('Home');

            function getValue(input) {
                var cond = input;
                if (input === 'Test') {
                    cond = 'show test';
                }
                return cond;
            };
        }]);
})(window.angular);
```

Using ng-switch you don't have to worry about multiple conditions and maintain cleaner code is easy unlike ng-if.